# An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. Missing `secret_key _base` for 'production' environment

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My ruby ​​version is "2.6.6", my mysql version is "5.7", my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I caused the error "Missing `secret_key _base` for 'production' environment" even though I set up the environment variable.

database.yml

```
# MySQL. Versions 5.0 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-client.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_USERNAME") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD") %>
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ****_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: ****_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  database: ****_production
  username: ****
  password: <%= ENV['****_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

secrets.yml

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rails secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.

development:
  secret_key_base: ****

test:
  secret_key_base: ****

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I added the `GENERETED CODE` of `rails secret`(I also executed `bundle exec rake secret`.) by the four following methods.

```
1. $ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED CODE
```

```
2. $ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED CODE
```

3. I added the GENERATED CODE to `~/.bash_profile`.

```
  export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED CODE
```

And then I saved the above SECRET_KEY_BASE with <kbd>esc</kbd>, "`:x`" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.And I executed this command`$ source ~/.bash_profile`.

4. I added the GENERATED CODE to `./env` file

```
DATABASE_USERNAME = ****
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ****
SECRET_KEY_BASE = GENERATED CODE
```

end.

I verified that the environment variable is set in Linux by the three following methods:

```
$ heroku config:get SECRET_KEY_BASE

GENERATED CODE
```

or

```
$ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE

SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED CODE
```

and

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE

GENERATED CODE
```

end.

As a result, Heroku didn't open but there are two messages of the error:

1. I executed this command:`$ heroku open`.

But Heroku didn't open but the following message was displayed.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

2. I executed this command:`$ heroku logs` and the following message was displayed.

```
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key
_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

end.

I can't open Heroku ,even though I set up the environment variable ,according to the two above messages.

Maybe I think that I can't open Heroku because MySQL version currently in use　"5.7"　and MySQL version with this command `$ mysql --version` don't match.

I executed this command`$ mysql --version`.

```
$ mysql --version

mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for osx10.16 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

end.

The following is the evidence that I use MySQL"5.7".

```
$ brew services start mysql@5.7
==> Successfully started `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
```

end.

What's the true cause why I can't open Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a couple of details:

- MySQL has nothing to do with this error, so you can edit that out from your question.
- Nothing in your local linux machine environment has nothing to do with the error, so you can remove any reference to `printenv`, `echo` and `export`.

**My guess: `config/secrets.yml` is git-ignored**

The most likely reason heroku does not see your SECRET_KEY_BASE env variable is that the `secrets.yml` file itself never goes to heroku.

If the `config/secrets.yml` file is never uploaded from your computer, heroku has no way to find it. Unlike `DATABASE_URL`, the secret key base does not have a "default" environment variable from which it is read.

***How to check***

If your project is in github/gitlab/other, you can check there, if you cannot find `config/secrets.yml` then it's not going to get to heroku either. If instead you don't have any other remote, check your `.gitignore` file (it contains the list of files that should not be uploaded when you push, to say it in some way); it probably includes a line saying `config/secrets.yml`.

Another way to check this is to change something (even a comment) in `config/secrets.yml`, and save. Then write `git status` in the same directory: if it says "no changes", then you have your `config/secrets.yml` ignored.

***What to do***

The easiest way is to go to `config/environments/production.rb`, and set your secret key base directly:

```rb
# somehwere inside the configure block
config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

Once you commit and push this change, you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. Your answer is best!!